# Divs daughters does not follow the parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a system of tabs and their contents I put a list of photo galleries. 
As the number of list elements (li) increases, the parent div (#content) is not increasing along. 
I want to follow the parent div div daughter. 
What is the error? How to solve?

See the picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xONVz.png

Below are my codes.

HTML: http://pastebin.com/f17Lq0v0
CSS: http://pastebin.com/3VJaWFqC

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle with the appropriate code sections

Comment: his codes in a fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/45e3J/ enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set an explicit height for your `#content` div. Either remove the height, or add the following to your CSS:

```
#content { overflow: auto; }
```

This should solve your problem.

[JSFiddle example with overflow: auto](http://jsfiddle.net/nXHK4/)

[JSFiddle example with height removed](http://jsfiddle.net/nXHK4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use this `#content { overflow: auto; }` it may help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove the `height` attribute of the `#content div`.

If you do it like this, the content wraps all around your `li`

But I can not test it properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Here its working- http://jsfiddle.net/2G2fa/2/**

"#content" height was fixed that's why it was not increasing with li and no need to add `"float:left"` in ".galeria-data" so we can remove `<br style="clear: both;">`.